# Howto create a grid like iTunes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I trying to draw a grid like Apple does in iTunes. A grid of images with an expanding row between the rows when you click one of the items in the grid.

After some googling and searching Stackoverflow all I found was [IKImageBrowserView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html) and [NSCollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030). Both options didn't work for me as I could not fit an extra row between the rows of the grid.

As a last resort I'm thinking about using something like NSTableView with NSTableViewGroupCell as a expanding row. But it feels dirty to me. Anyone any experience with this? Need some help to get me in the right direction here.

Comment: You could use an NSCollectionView and have extra items that are originally height zero and then expand them when you want an extra row.  Or you can have multiple NSCollectionViews (one per row, e.g.) and add new ones when needed.  I would try to make NSCollectionView work, personally, over a third party solution, though it is iOS 6+ only.  I use PSTCollectionView to get the same functionality on earlier versions.

Comment: @jeffamaphone - I agree with you that using `NSCollectionView` is the preferred option, but I think this question is talking about OS X, not iOS.

Comment: It's a OS X app indeed. The hidden row is something I tried but failed terribly. Maybe I need to try it again.